# Default value as positional argument to settings is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, dry-validation

I am going to maintain a rails application locally on Mac M1 based computer.

OS Version: Monterey 12.1

Ruby version 2.6.6

Rails version 4.2.11

I am getting this error and can't figure out what is actually causing this error to raise.
The error logged in console:

```
/Users/shimolkhan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/dry-validation-0.13.3/lib/dry/validation/schema/class_interface.rb:8:in `<module:Validation>' [dry-configurable] default value as positional argument to settings is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version Provide a `default:` keyword argument instead
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be a small incompatibility between the versions of dry-validation and dry-configurable that you are running.

This deprecation was introduced into dry-configurable 0.13.0 (the latest version) recently here:
[Changelog](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-configurable/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) [Pull Request](https://github.com/dry-rb/dry-configurable/pull/111/commits/b118da004fa65772f25518046e4e77eaafc3b9fe)

Yet according to the fragment you pasted, you're running dry-validation 0.13.3, which is almost 3 years old.

I'd suggest updating your version of dry-validation and perhaps all dry gems.